# Why is a post limited to one question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Why is a post limited to one question on a particular subject? Why can't a user ask some more simple questions on the same subject?

Comment: _"if user asks multiple questions in one post,it will go on hold.why?"_ **No clutter!**

Comment: Cf. [Can I ask only one question per post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735) on Meta.SE

Comment: Multi-tasking is for computers, not humans. Though I manage to sip coffee and read, just on the surface

Comment: 1) This is a **Question** and Answer Site, not **Questions** - it's singular. 2) The site is designed around one question and a clear answer; if you post 3 questions, and 3 separate people each post an answer to a different question, which **single answer** do you accept as being helpful? 3) It keeps clutter and noise down, to make searches easier and answers easier to locate. 4) This isn't a personal tutorial or assistance site. We expect **you** to put the effort into finding answers yourself, and using these sites as a **last resort** after all other efforts have failed.

Comment: Oh, and 4) Because it's clearly stated as the policy in the [help] guidelines and explained in the [tour] pages, and users are expected to comply with those guidelines.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because we want the questions and the answers posted to Stack Overflow to be useful to others, not just the person posting the question.  Question posts consisting of many small questions amount to personalized counseling, which is not what we do here.

Comment: Also, lots of sub-questions presents opportunities for partial answers which makes accepting an answer more difficult (if you ask a four-part question and two people each answer two different parts, which one do you accept?).